# Why should I use nested try-catch blocks in Java?

Tags: java, exception

I really don't get the point in using nested try-catch blocks. They are difficult to read and sometimes non pretty straightforward. For instance:

```java
try {
 // do something
}
catch ( [exception_1] e) {}
catch ( [exception_2] e) {}
catch ( [exception_3] e) {}
```

The code above is more readable and I can understand what it does - if an exception occurs it can be handled by one of the catch blocks.
But if I use the nested form:

```java
try {
   try {
      try {
         // Do something for try-block 3
      }
      catch ( [exception_1] except_1) {};
      // Do something for try-block 2
   }
   catch ( [exception_2] except_2) {};
   // Do something for try-block 1
}
catch ( [exception_3] except_3) {}
```

The code above is a mess, but it achieves exactly the same of the first code. Or it doesn't? Help me figure this out.

Comment: You’ve misunderstood something. No one would rewrite that nested form as shown in your second example, not for a single operation. Your first example is appropriate for a single operation.

Comment: If you’re not in a situation where using nested try-catch makes sense to you, then you probably shouldn’t. I occasionally do use them in situations where they do make sense.

Comment: You have no actual code so it is unclear why you would use either form.  What is each block of exception-handling doing in response to the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - a bit contrived but demonstrates the point that the two try-catch structures are different - dependent on the actually implementation (this may be exactly what @KosztDojscia was pointing out so then consider this answer a duplicate) :

```
public class Main
{
    public static class Exception1 extends Exception { }
    public static class Exception2 extends Exception { }
    public static class Exception3 extends Exception { }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;

        // "messy" structure
        try {
            try {
                try {
                    i = 3; if (i == 3) throw new Exception1();
                } catch (Exception1 e1) { i = 300; }

                i = 4; if (i == 4) throw new Exception2();
    
            } catch (Exception2 e2) { i = 400; }
            
            i = 5; if (i == 5) throw new Exception3();

        } catch (Exception3 e3) { i = 500; }
        
        System.out.println(i);

        // "clean" structure            
        try {
            i = 3; if (i == 3) throw new Exception1();
            i = 4; if (i == 4) throw new Exception2();
            i = 5; if (i == 5) throw new Exception3();
        } catch (Exception1 e1) { i = 300; }
          catch (Exception2 e2) { i = 400; }
          catch (Exception3 e3) { i = 500; }

        System.out.println(i);

    }
}
```

Prints:

```
500
300
```

Answer (score 0):

Emm, it depends on how you write code. If some code will be used for example...

```java
try {
   try {
      -->in here<--
      try {
         // Do something for try-block 3
      }
      catch ( [exception_1] except_1) {};
      // Do something for try-block 2
   }
   catch ( [exception_2] except_2) {};
   // Do something for try-block 1
}
catch ( [exception_3] except_3) {}
```

then if exception_1 is raised, won't be caught. If everything will be used inside third try, then there is no difference.